# Why does Swift BooleanLiteralConvertible require a boolean literal?

Tags: swift

I am trying to add `BooleanLiteralConvertible` support to my class so I can instantiate it with a boolean. The thing that's throwing me for a loop is the distinction between a boolean value and a boolean *literal*.

For example, after adding the protocol I attempted this:

```
func setSelected(value: Bool) {
    var node: MyClass = value
}
```

But Swift complained that it cannot convert `Bool` to `MyClass`. It took me a while to realize it has to be a boolean *literal*. Oddly enough the following works fine:

```
func setSelected(value: Bool) {
    var node: MyClass = value ? true : false
}
```

…which seems just absolutely silly to me. Is there a legitimate reason for this seemingly very bizarre requirement?

Comment: Did you try `value!`?

Comment: `value` is already a non-optional `Bool`, I can't apply a `!` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the question.  Only the Swift team could definitively answer, but I can speculate as to why: converting a typed value into a variable of a different type without an explicit conversion or cast is very easy to confuse with a programmer error, and in many cases is something the compiler should warn about.

Example (and assume that `Person` is also a `StringLiteralConvertible` that can be initialized with a string variable as well as a literal as you pose in your question):

```
struct Person {

    private static var idCounter = 1

    var name:String
    let id:Int

    init(withName name:String) {
        Person.idCounter += 1
        self.name = name
        self.id = Person.idCounter
    }
}

var person = Person(withName:"Mary")
let name = "John"
person = name
```

The above code looks suspiciously like a mistake, where the programmer is assigning a value of the wrong type (`String`) to a variable of type `Person`. It may in fact *be* a mistake. Maybe the programmer only meant to change the *name* of the person (`person.name = name`) without creating a new `Person` with a new unique id. Or maybe the programmer intended to assign some other value to `person` but made a typo or code completion error.  Hard to tell without either being the original programmer, or carefully studying all the context to see whether this conversion makes sense. And it gets harder the further the assignment is from the place where the variables are originally initialized Should the compiler warn here that a value of type `String` is being assigned to a variable of type `Person`?

The example would be far more clear, and more in line with Swift conventions as:

```
var person = Person(withName:"Mary")
let name = "John"
person = Person(withName:name)
```

The above version is completely unambiguous, both to the compiler and to any other programmers who read this later.

Comment: Well it's clearly subjective at a point. I mean, why do we need literal convertibles in the first place if you're worried about code readability? `person = "Bob"` to me feels just as "wrong" as `person = name`, but if you allow one, why not the other? Personally I wanted to use this feature as a means to make my syntax more concise and easier to write. Constantly having to call an initializer just feels like boilerplate that could be avoided with implicit conversion. It's still statically valid and compile-time safe, even if it doesn't *look* familiar.

Comment: In fact, by introducing this restriction, the language is actually now creating a very strong semantic difference between the use of a literal value and the use of a variable of the same type, where in most languages these are completely interchangeable at a fundamental level. To me this feels very much like a step in the *wrong* direction, creating a branch point in the conceptual understanding of values and types and unnecessarily complicating the language.

Comment: @devios I think you bring up good points. There isn't a _huge_ difference between a literal notation and an actual typed value, but there are a couple I can think of:  1) literal notation forces specifying the value at the initialization site, e.g. `let thing = "Foo"` rather than `let thing = someStringValueWeDontKnow` which makes literals slightly less ambiguous and mistake-prone

Comment: @devios ... and 2) literals aren't technically types. They are untyped values that can be implicitly used to tell the compiler to construct instances of types.  So `"hello"` could be a String, a Selector, or a RegexExpression depending on context, just like `5` could be an Int or a Double. But `var something:String` means `something` _is_ a String and only a String, unless explicitly casted or converted.

Comment: @devios  I agree that these are fairly subtle distinctions, and there isn't a huge difference in most cases. So, either the Swift team decided to draw the line inside that small range of difference between usages for opinionated reasons, or perhaps there is some real complexity introduced to the compiler when it has to reason about when setting a variable to a strongly typed value of a _different_ type (without a cast or conversion) is allowed or not, vs. simply allowing type instantiation from literal notations, which it already knows how to do anyway.

Comment: @devios  Personally, I agree with you that Swift should move towards embracing more implicit conversions at call sites and in function parameters, in cases where those conversions have been explicitly defined by the programmer or the standard library. I'm planning to propose at least one example of that to the Swift Evolution mailing list, and encourage you to make your case there as well.  If we don't get the conciseness and ease-of-use we would like, at least we might get more of the rationale behind why these sorts of things are not supported.

Answer (score 6):

Types conforming to `BooleanLiteralConvertible` can be initialized with the Boolean **literals** `true` and `false`, e.g.

```
let mc : MyClass = true
```

This has nothing to do with initializing the type with a Boolean **value:**

```
let value : Bool = // ... some boolean value
let mc : MyClass = value // error: cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to specified type 'MyClass'
```

and there is – as far as I know – no way to make such an implicit
conversion work.  You would have to write a custom init method

```
init(bool : Bool) {
    // ...
}
```

and initialize the object as

```
let value : Bool = // ... some boolean value
let mc = MyClass(bool: value)
```

Comment: Another example of Swift's bipolar disorder, imo. ;) Sometimes Swift's power lends to some very concise and elegant syntax. Other times it makes you do things that would make an amateur cringe.

Comment: @devios: In early Swift releases you could implement implicit conversion methods from arbitrary types to your type. That feature was later removed, but I don't remember the rationale.